# What happens to Java heap when fork is called from JNI thread

Tags: java, java-native-interface

What happens to Java heap when `fork()` is called from JNI thread. Is the Java heap duplicated?

What will happen to native memory sections, JNI memory, Class Memory, Thread memory, and Thread Local Heap (TLH)?

Comment: I would expect the address spaces to be copied, as per the `fork(2)` manual page.  But I would not expect the child process to be a functional JVM ... because (for example) forking does not replicate parent processes threads in the child.  Since *every* JVM has / needs multiple threads, this is a show-stopper.

Comment: @StephenC What will happen to the Java threads that was alive in the parent process, Will all the java threads will not be runnable ?

Comment: Correct (apart from the thread that called `fork`).  Worse still, you will have lost the GC threads.  I would *expect* the child JVM to be massively broken, or even catatonic.  But feel free to try it ... and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

After calling `fork()`, the JVM as the child process will not work.  Per [the POSIX documentation on `fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html):

> A process shall be created with a single thread. If a multi-threaded
>   process calls `fork()`, the new process shall contain a replica of the
>   calling thread and its entire address space, possibly including the
>   states of mutexes and other resources. Consequently, to avoid errors,
>   **the child process may only execute async-signal-safe operations until such time as one of the `exec` functions is called.**

A JVM is a multithreaded process, and JNI calls and Java functions are not POSIX async-signal-safe function calls.

See [**2.4 Signal Concepts**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) for the list of function calls POSIX requires to be async-signal-safe.

So, what happens to the Java heap, and other JVM-specific memory?  They're copied into the child process's virtual address space, normally via [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write), but they're effectively unusable should you try continuing JVM execution in the child process.  They're in an unknown state, with locks potentially held by non-existent threads, for example.